# What is the intrinsic name of a function?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I understand that instrinsic names are assigned to refer to functions when these said functions refer to other functions.
eg: f=max  is f the intrinsic name or max?

Comment: What do you mean by "intrinsic name"?

Comment: I'm not sure. That's why I need clarification.

Answer (score 6):

If you mean the `__name__` property, it's the name that was used in the `def` statement that created the function.

```
Python 3.3.1 (v3.3.1:d9893d13c628, Apr  6 2013, 20:25:12) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (In
tel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def f ():
...     return 0
...
>>> f.__name__
'f'
>>> g = f
>>> g.__name__
'f'
>>>
```

Built-in functions have `__name__` properties matching their preset names.

```
>>> max.__name__
'max'
>>> h = max
>>> h.__name__
'max'
>>>
```

Functions that were created by some other means than a `def` statement may have default values for the `__name__` property.

```
>>> (lambda: 0).__name__
'<lambda>'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the **intrinsic name** as the name of user-defined `def` function. Consider two ways to bind a function to a name `square`:

```
 def square(x):
     return x * x
```

In this `def` statement, both creating function and assigning name happens at the same time and this `def` statement gives the function an intrinsic name. `square` is "function square" here.

```
 square = lambda x : x * x
```

Whereas, `lambda` creates a function `lambda x : x * x` **without** a name. The assignment statement `square =` assigns the value of the function to the name. `square` is "function **lambda**" here.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to look at the frames.

```
f = max
max = 3
f(2,3,4)
```

Global frame

f ----------------> func max(...) # object

max: 3

Notice that the function object says max. That is the intrinsic name!